# Run Ansible playbook command from gitlabci

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I recently learned cloudformation module in ansible and looking to use the same with gitlab CI.

Below is my playbook:

```
- name: provision stack
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  # Launch the cloudformation-example.yml template.  Register the output.

  tasks:
  - name: launch ansible cloudformation example
    cloudformation: >
      stack_name="ansible-cloudformation" state=present
      region=us-east-1 disable_rollback=true
      template=files/simple-rds.yml
    args:
      template_parameters:
        vpcid: vpc-0123456
        application: abc
        appSubnetCidr1: 201.0.0.0/20
        appSubnetCidr2: 201.0.0.0/22
        dbCreateNewParamsGroup: true
        dbInstanceType: db.t2.micro
        dbName: testdb
        dbSubnetId1: subnet-87654321
        dbSubnetId2: subnet-12345678
        dbUsername: master_user
        environment: development
        product: ""
        dbPassword: ""
        techContact: ""
    register: stack
  - name: show stack events
    debug: msg="My stack events are {{stack.events}}"
```

Now I want to run this playbook using gitlab CI. For that, I have created a generic ansible image, So that I use the same image for running different playbooks.

Ansible image Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
# File Author / Maintainer

# Install ansible
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN apt-get update
#RUN apt-add-repository -y ppa:ansible/ansible
#RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install ansible

# Install Pip
RUN apt install python-pip -y

# Install boto3
RUN pip install boto3

# Install boto
RUN pip install boto
```

Now In .gitlab-ci.yml.

```
stages:
  - build

build:master:
  image: vrathore/ansibleimage:latest
  script:
    - touch  ~/.boto
    - echo "[Credentials]" > ~/.boto
    - echo "aws_access_key_id = AKIAIACZXXXXXXXXXXXX" >> ~/.boto
    - echo "aws_secret_access_key = P5lO8H9tXXXXXXXXXXXXX" >> ~/.boto
    - cp simple-rds.yml /etc/ansible/playbook/files/simple-rds.yml
    - cp eb_playbook.yml /etc/ansible/playbook/eb_playbook.yml
    - cd /etc/ansible/playbook && ansible-playbook eb_playbook.yml -vvv
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
```

In the above script I am adding credential in boto file and copying playbook script (eb_playbook.yml) and cloudformation script(simple-rds.yml) and running the playbook run command but I am getting

```
cp: cannot stat 'simple-rds.yml': No such file or directory
```

How can I copy both files (eb_playbook.yml and simple-rds.yml). both files present in gitlab project and run the ansible playbook command.

Comment: if you remove the simple-rds line does the eb_playbook line work?  The error is saying it can't find the file.